# SOAP Server Application on Delphi XE8 communicate with SQL database

Tags: sql-server, web-services, delphi, soap, delphi-xe8

I have created a SOAP Server Application on Delphi XE8. 
I used it as a ISAPI SOAP service, with interface and implementation files.

I deployed this service on IIS, and called it's functions from a VCL client.

I am now trying to make a new function on the SOAP service that communicates with a MSSQL database on the SQL server.
But every time i create a new Data module on the SOAP server, the service stops working.

Can anyone please tell me how to make a database layer, then connect my SOAP service to it, to be able to call from other clients.

Note : I am creating ISAPI.dll

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a CGI executable?

Comment: Did you call CoInitialize inside your DLL main?

Comment: If you are creating a CGI .exe or an ISAPI .dll make sure you have permissions on SQL Server. You make your service run under a username by going to IIS, selecting your application and clicking on Advance Settings. Then set your user/pass in Physical Path and try your service again. If it works then we know the problem, leaving your username and password there is not the solution. Talk with your systems administrator for a solid solution.

Comment: thank you sir, but i am a beginner and still don't know how to even organize my data layer with my service layer. any help or example would be highly appreciated.